# Increase size of PhpStorm error squiggly line (underwave)

Tags: ide, phpstorm, usability, jetbrains-ide

Stupid tiny thing.

PhpStorm is great but when I cut and paste code sometimes I leave off a `;` or a `}` or sometimes I have another dumb problem. PS is good at finding these trouble is it uses a fine underwave which is quite difficult to see. I know all about `F2` going to next error etc. I would just love to be able to make the error pointer more obvious so I can just look at the screen and see it - a bright red highlight over the missing character or whatever. (Spot the missing `;` below.)

[image]

I have trawled SO and the rest of the Interweb and have spent ages in `Settings` but cannot find anyway to beef this up. Any ideas where the setting for this might be?

**EDIT:** Just in case anyone comes this way again this is what a missing semicolon looks like now. Basically I never forget the closing semi colon or { as I have a great big red light shining in my face - perfect for a typing clutz like me.

[image]

(If you found this useful please uptick - but there seem v few phpStorm Troopers here.)

Answer (score 3):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts`
2. `General | Errors & Warnings`
3. Choose the right style (e.g. `Error` or `Warning`) and change its settings.

   You will not be able to make underwave bolder, but you can choose more brighter color (which may look a bit bolder to human eye) or change underwave to another style.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. When I was searching for "error" or "error  highlight " it went to that page but highlighted nothing and I did not understand what was going on. I Now have errors as a nice bright red block with white lettering. V easy to spot. Thanks a million.